# Ionic 4 OneSignal getIds big delay

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, onesignal

I'm using Ionic 4 (Angular) with one signal for a push notification (OneSignal Cordova Plugin and one signal via npm).
When I use the getIds () function I have a long delay to get the user ids (userId and token), it takes between 30 seconds and 2 minutes. In some cases, these ids do not come back.

I tried switching from lifecycle, retrieving before or after initializeApp, I tried using addSubscriptionObserver and also addPermissionObserver. All have the same result, this great delay from 30 seconds to 2 minutes and in some cases does not return.

This is the code I am currently using inside the initializeApp() (the initiliazeApp is called in the constructor) in the app.component.ts of Ionic 4 (Angular):

```
this.oneSignal.startInit(this.onesignal_appid, this.firebase_senderid);
this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.InAppAlert);

this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe((res) => {
    // do something when notification is received
});

this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe((res) => {
    // do something when a notification is opened
});

this.oneSignal.endInit();

this.getNotificationPlayerIds()
    .then((ids) => {
        console.log('first get ids: ', ids);
        this.notificationPlayerIds = ids;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log('first get ids error: ', e);
    });

  getNotificationPlayerIds() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        this.oneSignal.getIds()
          .then((ids) => {
            resolve(ids);
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            reject(e);
          })
      }
    })
  }
```

I hope these ids return as soon as possible so that I can save this data in the user object in the database.
Is there anything in the code that is incorrect and causes this or is it a really plugin/node module (npm) problem? I even opened an issue on the ionic-team, but without success.
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/3046

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The delay issue is most likely a problem with the device getting a player id due to a networking issue. Turning on Verbose logging and checking the logcat or Xcode log should pinpoint your issue.